# Remove multiple positions in array

Tags: javascript

I have the following array

```java
myArray = ["zell", "allen", 34, 223344, age , "Stree 45"]
```

i need to delete every position which be length less than 4

in this case the position 2 and 4

I wrote

```java
    for(var i=0; i<myArray.length; i++){
        if(myArray[i].trim().length<3){
        myArray.splice(i,1); 
        }
    }
```

but works only with the first one, I need with every one

thanks

Comment: what is `data`? I guess you meant `myArray`? You should start from the end, as each time you modify the array, you change what your for loop should be doing as you're shifting left the other values, but won't process them and will try to read past the end of the array...

Comment: yes, sorry, fixed

Comment: I can't see this working at all, since `34` is a Number, which does not have a `trim` method, so you would find you have an exception, and nothing has changed

Comment: Also, the answer depends on one other point. Do you want to mutate `myArray` in place, in which case you would use splice, but you would iterate from the last item to the first; or, if can you assign a new array to `myArray`, you would use `filter` method

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can filter out the items that are shorter then 4 chars:

```js
var myArray = ["zell", "allen", 34, 223344, "age" , "Stree 45"];
var filteredArr = myArray.filter(item => item.toString().length >= 4);
console.log(filteredArr);
```

Comment: this works as long as the requirement isn't to mutate `myArray`

Comment: @Bravo ... I don't think ```myArray``` is getting mutated here!

Comment: crack! thanks, it works

Comment: sorry, I meant IS, not ISN'T :p

Comment: Then you are right @Bravo! :-)